# Youtube api V3 nuget error visual studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to install Youtube api V3 using nuget package manager console

I'm typing there `Install-Package Google.Apis.YouTube.v3`

but i got an error

`Install-Package : The 'Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.9' package requires NuGet client version '2.8.1' or above, but the current NuGet version is '2.6.40627.9000'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Google.Apis.YouTube.v3
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], NuGetVersionNotSatisfiedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand`

Is there any way to solve that?

I need that because I'm getting error when I'm including:

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data;
using Google.Apis.Upload;
```

`Error  2   The type or namespace name 'Apis' does not exist in the namespace 'Google' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Have you looked in the "Tools / Extensions and Updates" menu to see if you can update the version of NuGet that's installed in VS2012?

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks a lot solved. please write that as answer and I'll mark as solved to help other developers when they'll face same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically just need to update the version of NuGet installed with Visual Studio.

Go to the Tools menu and select "Extensions and updates", then find "NuGet Package Manager" (at least that's what I assume it's called, based on what I see in VS2013) you should be offered the option to update it. The updated version should be fine to use to install all the dependencies you need.

Comment: For Visual Studio 2012, it is called "NuGet Package Manager".